# SQLITE doesn't sum float values correctly

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

I have a table which name is "ventas" (it means 'sales')
the idea is to get a query to sum all those sales...

[image: this is the table]

if you sum all numbers, you get 146.2

and then these are my queries:

```
    SELECT total(importe) as suma FROM ventas
    SELECT sum(importe) as suma FROM ventas
```

and result is (for both queries):
151.2 (which is not mathematically correct)

any ideas?
Thanks!

```
    CREATE TABLE [ventas] (
      [id_venta] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      [id_turno] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
      [id_usuario] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
      [fecha] DATETIME  NOT NULL,
      [importe] FLOAT  NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (id_turno) REFERENCES ventas(id_turno)
    )
```

Comment: What are the data types of the column?  If it is not the right data type it may be rounding before adding

Comment: Are you sure the table in your screenshot contains all of the data?

Comment: I'll add the table's schema.

Comment: second question, yes. absolutely! It's very strange

Comment: How are you able to sum with commas in between numbers?

Comment: are you connected to the correct DB file?

Comment: This is how the SQLITE admin displays the float numbers according to my culture. but internally, my understanding is that is saved with '.'

Comment: @DanielMarcus That's how the European "decimal" is represented.

Comment: just for your understanding I use comma as decimal separator

Comment: Thanks @PhilNDeBlanc

Comment: @juergend yes, I perform the query connected to the same bd! actually I don't know what is happening

Comment: float is a non-precise data type - have you tried using decimal?

Comment: I didn't try it, I am afraid I should try altought didn't want it :S